# Does go copy return value every time?

Tags: go

For example,

```golang
func foo() {
    return map[string]interface{}{}
}

func baz(){
    a := foo()
}
```

every time the `baz()` was called, was the `map` also copied? If yes and the map is very complex, would the process take much time to do the copy operation?

Comment: Yes, the map is copied. No, copying a map is O(1).

Comment: If the returned value is a struct, would it be slow? @Volker

Comment: Everything is passed (and returned) by value, which means a copy is made. Maps are implemented as pointers, so passing (and returning) a map simply passes (and returns) a pointer value under the hood.

Comment: @PaulZhang you need to define "slow".

Comment: It's bad practice to think about "slow" or "fast" _unless_ realistic load tests have identified that this code path is hot and the bottleneck  of the application. Sometimes it's sensible to not do things badly but most of the time when people think about "will this be slow" it doesn't matter the slightest as this is not the code part making the application slow.

Comment: In this case, nothing is getting _copied_. Each invocation of `foo` (and, therefore, of`baz`) simply initialises a new map.

Answer (score 0):

In that case a new pointer to a map is created each time the function is executed.

> Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices, and so the value of m above is nil; it doesn’t point to an initialized map.

See: https://go.dev/blog/maps

Also, go has pointers to decide when to return a copy or not.
For example https://go.dev/play/p/Pibhj5onIIL